# After Flushing DNS on Mac, IP still showing incorrectly

Tags: mac, dns, ip, dd-wrt

I'm working with a website that changed servers, and even after it fully switching over, I still get the old IP when doing nslookup.

I've tried flushing my DNS on my router and computer, and it still fails to return the correct IP.

Via DD-WRT Shell: killall -1 dnsmasq
Via Mac (10.6) shell:

Comment: Do you have a local host file that might be returning the incorrect IP? Can you try running nslookup and specifying an external server like OpenDNS to see what the IP resolves to? What OS are you running?

Comment: I ran an online NSlookup from MyDNSTools and it shows the new IP.

Comment: Global propagation of DNS changes can take up to 24 hours. Try a different DNS server (like Google's): `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8`

Comment: **DNS does not propagate.  It's a cached system.**  The questioner apparently knows this, as xe is trying to flush caches.  Xe probably hasn't flushed _all_ of the caches that are involved.  Moreover: The 24 hours figure is untrue.  Caching depends from TTLs, which many caching servers will allow to be anything from 1 second to 1 week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS changes must be renewed by other DNS servers, it usually takes some time, depending upon the caching of the DNS server you use.

Take a look at this site to find if your domain has been cached to all the DNS servers.

[whatsmydns.net](http://www.whatsmydns.net/)

Comment: DNS does not propagate. Changes are *never* "sent to all the DNS servers", especially because the majority of those servers are not interested in your domain. DNS information is *requested* and *cached*.

Comment: @grawity ok did not know that.